# Typeahead with Array of Tokens

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, autocomplete, typeahead

I'm using Typeahead and trying to add an array of tokens.

See fiddle: I type "astronomy a" and all is good. After I add the next character, "n" to "astronomy an", typeahead decides that there are no longer matches.

When I comment out both of the tokens lines, it will match the entire string "astronomy and physics".

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong for the life of me.

Full example on JsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/sr4136/qkZEx/

```
var json=[
    {
    "name":"Astronomy and Physics",
    "tokens":["astronomy and physics", "testwords", "something"]
    },
    {
    "name":"another thing",
    "tokens":["mer", "words", "word space"]
    }
];

$(".programs-search .text").typeahead([{
    name: 'programs',
    local: json,
    limit: 10,
    minLength: '3',
    valueKey: 'name'
}]);
```

Comment: So it appears that typeahead doesn't support spaces in tokens..

Answer (score -1):

You can only use single words in tokens. no phrases.